# DLL in bin folder works in IIS but not in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a website where I load a third party DLL using this function, which I got from an open source project using the same DLL:

```
public static void LoadCodecs(string path = null, string search = null) {
    if (path == null)
        path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var catalog = (search == null) ?
        new DirectoryCatalog(path) :
        new DirectoryCatalog(path, search);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    foreach (var lazy in container.GetExports<ICodec>()) {
        var codec = lazy.Value;
        _codecs[codec.TransferSyntax] = codec;
    }
}
```

I have the DLL in the Bin folder along with my DLLs on a server running IIS.  It works fine there (on the webserver).   When I try to debug the website in Visual Studio (2012, ultimate edition, on my development machine) I get a "Could not load file or assembly" exception complaining about this specific DLL when trying to access any page.  Both the server and my development machine are 64 bit, so I don't think that's the problem.  When I delete the DLL, the website works fine (except for the pages that use the codecs loaded by the function above).

[EDIT]
It looks like my problem is that Visual Studio is running a 32 bit web hosting environment - when I put the 32 bit version of my DLL, it works.

Now I'm using this to select the correct DLL:

```
string file = "Codecs";//name of 32 bit DLL minus extension
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
    file += "64";//64 bit dll is Codecs64
}
file += ".dll";
LoadCodecs(file);//just illustrative, actually need correct path here
```

But this still only works if I only put the correct version in the Bin directory.  Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: your dll is probably 32 bits (it does not matter if your system is 32 or 64, it is up to .net framework to decide if it runs your process as 32 or 64), try configuring your project specifically for each CPU architecture so that you can figure out which one actually works, or test your dll with [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com)

Comment: Have you tried to enable fusion log? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @yms - my DLL is 64 bit - I have a 32 bit version also, but only the 64 bit version works in IIS (unless I set the "allow 32 bit" flag in the app pool)

Comment: It looks like my problem is that Visual Studio is running a 32 bit web hosting environment - when I put the 32 bit version of my DLL, it works.  Thanks yms for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Post your finding as an answer and accept it please.